# Code First with multiple relations to same table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a type that's called `ShipDoc` which has a reference to 3 `Users`:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmploymentDate { get; set; }
}

public class ShipDoc
{
    public int ShipDocId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    //....
    public int IssuedById { get; set; } //redundant
    public virtual User IssuedBy { get; set; }

    public int? VeiriedById { get; set; } //redundant + Nullable
    public virtual User VerifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int? ReceivedById { get; set; } //redundant + Nullable
    public virtual User ReceivedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When running the Update-Database command, in addition to the fields that are marked as redundant, `EF` adds 3 other fields and use them as the FK's. the 3 new fields that are added are: `IssuedBy_UserId`, `VeiriedBy_UserId`,`ReceivedBy_UserId`. I can see the convention that's being used here but I wonder if I can choose the names myselsf.

Comment: `HasForeignKey` http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/hh134698.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ForeignKey` attribute to use your `int` fields as foreign keys.

```
public int IssuedById { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("IssuedById")]
public virtual User IssuedBy { get; set; }
```

Column in database will have the name generated by `IssuedById` property. If you want to change that you can use `Column` attribute.